# How to send PUT request with a file and an array of data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, put

I am programing a web app using Laravel as API and Angularjs as frontend. I have a form to update product using PUT method with a array of informations and a file as product image. But I couldn't get the input requests in the controller, it was empty.

Please see the code below :

web.php ( route )

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::put('products/{id}', 'ProductController@update');
});
```

My angularjs product service :

```
function update(productId, data, onSuccess, onError){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('imageFile', data.imageFile);
        formData.append('image', data.image);
        formData.append('name', data.name);
        formData.append('category_id', data.category_id);
        formData.append('price', data.price);
        formData.append('discount', data.discount);
        Restangular.one("/products", productId).withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity}).customPUT(formData, undefined, undefined,   {'Content-Type': undefined}).then(function(response) {

                onSuccess(response);

            }, function(response){

                onError(response);

            }
        );
    }
```

My ProductController update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
// Just print the request data
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

This is what I see in Chrome inspectmen
[image: Put header][image: Sended data]
[image: Result was empty]

Please share your experiences on this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Paste your routes, views and controllers code snippet please. Let us know what you have tried so far. Without these information no one can help with this little information.

Comment: I updated the question. Please have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

what you need is Only normal POST request with new field named _method=put then your code will work normally:

[image]

Comment: Laravel fake PUT by using POST but with hidden input text named _method

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, according to [this discussion](http://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-i-can-not-get-inputs-from-a-putpatch-request). What you should do instead is to 'fake' the PUT request by using [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
public update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->someVar;
    $request->file('someFile');

    // Get variables into an array.
    $array = $request->all();
```

Also, make sure you're using `Route::put` or `Route::resource` for your route.

Comment: $request->all() was empty. Please help!